# SDL CMake Error

Tags: compilation, linker, cmake, sdl

When running cmake . in my project directory, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL (missing: SDL_LIBRARY SDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindSDL.cmake:176 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( MoakRaster )
add_executable( MoakRaster MoakRaster.c )
find_package (SDL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries (MoakRaster ${SDL_LIBRARY})
```

I've installed and removed and reinstalled both libsdl2-2.0 and libsdl2-2.0dev a hundred times, and downloaded the source and installed all the dependencies the source had, just in case sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0 wasn't including all of the dependencies.

The only thing I haven't done yet is compile the binary from the source code, which I'd rather not do because I'd prefer to keep extraneous files out of my project for now. If this is a known issue with FindSDL.cmake however, I'll start looking into making my own binary :/

EDIT: Apparently I needed SDL1.2.

EDIT2: And apparently SDL1.2 is borked now, since most of the documentation out there is for SDL2.0. Plus, none of the SDL calls/types work. Back to where I started.

EDIT3: Forget it, switching back to gcc. cmake and SDL are borked. It works.

Comment: The find script that currently ships with CMake (`FindSDL.cmake`) only works for SDL 1.x. You will need to write your own find mechanism for SDL2.Fortunately, you are not the first person to run into this problem, so there are a couple of existing scripts floating around. [This one](https://github.com/brendanwhitfield/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake) for example seems rather nice.